# How to obtain Redis URL from Helm dependency

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm

In my `Charts.yaml` for the helm chart I am working on, I have a [Redis dependency](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/redis)

```
dependencies:
  - name: redis
    version: "18.4.0"
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

Now, I would like to construct a Redis URL to be used as a secret for the other resources.

Hence, I would like to be able to set in my deployment something like

```
env:
- name: REDIS_URL
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: {{ .Values.secret.secretName }}
      key: REDIS_URL
```

my question is now, how I could obtain the Redis URL, such that it looks like

```
  REDIS_URL="rediss://<user_name>:<user_pw>@<redis host>:<port>"
```

or

```
  REDIS_URL="redis://<user_name>:<user_pw>@<redis host>:<port>"
```

Ideally, it would be a connection within the cluster and the same namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Helm doesn't have a good general way to pass computed values from a dependency chart to its parent.  Often the best answer winds up being to inspect the dependency chart and see what it's creating.

For the [bitnami/redis](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/redis) chart, you can find [the primary Service](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/redis/templates/master/service.yaml) winds up being named `{{ .Release.Name }}-redis-master`; its [Secret](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/redis/templates/secret.yaml) is just `{{ .Releae.Name }}-redis`, and has a single key `redis-password`; and there is no particular username setting anywhere in the chart.  Redis's [default password authentication mode](https://redis.io/docs/management/security/#authentication) uses a single shared password.  As is typical in container environments, the port will always be the standard Redis port 6379.

However, you can't directly incorporate one Secret value into another Secret, and it's not usually good practice to try to read back the Secret from your Helm chart code.  If you're just trying to get the URL into your application in that format, I'd construct it as a set of environment variables, which can be dynamically set from Secrets or concatenated:

```yaml
{{- define "myapp.env.redis" -}}
- name: REDIS_HOST
  value: {{ .Release.Name }}-redis-master
- name: REDIS_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: {{ .Release.Name }}-redis
      key: redis-password
- name: REDIS_URL
  value: redis://redis:$(REDIS_PASSWORD)@$(REDIS_HOST):6379/0
{{- end -}}

env:
{{ include "myapp.env.redis | indent 2 }}
```

Note that the Redis chart has a couple of different ways to set that Secret.  You could try to read `.Values.redis.auth.password`, for example, but it isn't necessarily set.